# How to pass a reference to class into another class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

The question is a bit silly. I am trying to implement a skill updating system. So to explain.

There is a class

```
class AppInfo
{
    public static var power:int = 10;
    public static var speed:int = 20;

}
```

and class SmartButton which should take a reference to one of the static variables e.g. power in a constructor and increment it on the given value.

e.g.

```
class SmartButton
{
   public function onClick(skillReference:int = <AppInfo.power>, incrementVAlue:int = 10)
   {
        skillReference += incrementVAlue

   }

}
```

I want this code to update the value of the power in AppInfo class. But this doesn't happen... I assume because the skill was passed as value not as reference...

Can you suggest a way of solving the task?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, `ints` are passed by value rather than reference. One direct approach would be to encapsulate power into a reference type (a `class`) rather than a value type:

```
class Skill {
    public var value:int;

    public function Skill(val:int) {
        this.value = val;
    }
}

class AppInfo
{
    public static var power:Skill = new Skill(10);
    public static var speed:Skill = new Skill(20);

}
```

Then passing `power` should pass it as a reference to the instance. Though you would have to change your implemenation a bit to use `skillReference.value` instead.

Aside from that, I think there are a couple of ways to abstract what you want out. One way would be use an interface and leverage some dependency injection.

```
interface ISkills
{
    function get power():int;
    function set power(val:int):void;
}

class AppInfo implements ISkills
{
    private static _power:int = 0;

    public function get power():int { return _power; }  
    public function set power(val:int):void { _power = val; }
}

class SmartButton
{
   public function onClick(skills:int = ISkills, skill:String = "power", incrementVAlue:int = 10)
   {
        skills[skill] += incrementVAlue
   }
}
```

The idea here that you want to decouple your usage from your implementation. In this case `SmartButton` doesn't need to know how Skills work just how to operate on them. It loses its reference to the static class `AppInfo` in favor of an injectable instance. There are some advantages to this approach, it makes it easier to test and easier to swap implementations later if you decide that a static class isn't the best implementation idea without having to update a bunch of classes/code. Also, rather than injecting `ISkills` into the method, you could inject it into the constructor of `SmartButton`, and keep a `private` reference to the skill container.

Another approach would be to use a functional approach.

```
class SmartButton
{
    public var defaultWorker:Function = function(val:int):void {
        AppInfo.power += val;
    }

    public function onClick(worker:Function = undefined, incrementValue:int = 10):void
    {
        if(worker == undefined) worker = defaultWorker;
        worker.call(this, incrementValue);
    }
}
```

Again, in this case, rather than tightly coupling your implementation to use the `AppInfo` class directly, you inject a "worker" for it do the work for you (if the worker is `undefined` then use the default worker. You can then swap out which property gets changed by changing the closure that gets passed in. For instance if you wanted to change `speed` instead then you would call:

```
var smartButton:SmartButton;
smartButton.onClick(function(val:int):void { AppInfo.speed += val});
```

Not quite as succinct as it could be, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

The obligatory "elegantly sophisticated" approach using the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):

```
Interface Command {
    function execute():void;
}

Class UpdatePower implements Command {
    private var appInfo:AppInfo;
    private var delta:int;

    public function UpdatePower(appInfo:AppInfo, delta:int) {
        this.appInfo = appInfo;
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    public function execute():void {
        appInfo.delta += delta;
    }
}

Class SmartButton {
    var command:Command;

    public function SmartButton(command:Command) {
        this.command = command; 
    }

    public function onClick(event:Event):void {
        command.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably implement this in a slightly different way.

Maybe something like;

```
class Properties {
 private var _properties:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

     public function setValue(key:String, value:int) {
       _properties[key] = value;
    }

    public function getValue(key:String):int {
        if( !_properties[key] ) return 0;
        else return _properties[key];
    }

    public function modifyValue(key:String, value:int) {
        setValue(key, getValue(key) + value);
    }
}

class SmartButton
{
    public function onClick(target:Properties, key:String, incrementValue:int = 10) {
        target.modifyValue(key, incrementValue);
    }
}
```

Or something along those lines.